# What is system prompt in fine tuning of GPT3.5 for natural language to sql queries

Tags: language-model, sql, gpt, prompt-engineering

What exactly is a system prompt while finetuning GPT3.5 or a language model in general? How can I build system prompt for the task of converting natural language to SQL queries